# PHP Sorting Array of Hashes based on index

Tags: php

Have a php array of hashes below.  want to sort it based on the index.  array should be arranges as arr[0] , arr[1],arr[18] , `arr[22]` . instead of 
`arr[0]` ,`arr[1]`,`arr[22]`,`arr[18]`.  Want the sorting to be based on array index and not on hash inside the array.  How can i do it.  Tried asort it didnt work properly.

```
php > $arr=array();
php > $arr[0]['callbacks']=10;
php > $arr[0]['preview']=11;
php > $arr[0]['Dialer']=12;
php > $arr[1]['callbacks']=20;
php > $arr[1]['preview']=21;
php > $arr[1]['Dialer']=22;

php > $arr[22]['callbacks']=210;
php > $arr[22]['preview']=208;
php > $arr[22]['Dialer']=222;
php > $arr[18]['callbacks']=210;
php > $arr[18]['Dialer']=222;
php > $arr[18]['preview']=208;
php > print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [callbacks] => 10
            [preview] => 11
            [Dialer] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [callbacks] => 20
            [preview] => 21
            [Dialer] => 22
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [callbacks] => 210
            [preview] => 208
            [Dialer] => 222
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [callbacks] => 210
            [Dialer] => 222
            [preview] => 208
        )

)
php >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort it with `ksort($arr);`

Answer (score 1):

@Arav why don't you try `ksort()` php function it will sort your array according to key like below:

```
<?php
     $arr=array();
    $arr[0]['callbacks']=10;
    $arr[0]['preview']=11;
    $arr[0]['Dialer']=12;
    $arr[1]['callbacks']=20;
    $arr[1]['preview']=21;
    $arr[1]['Dialer']=22;

    $arr[22]['callbacks']=210;
    $arr[22]['preview']=208;
    $arr[22]['Dialer']=222;
    $arr[18]['callbacks']=210;
    $arr[18]['Dialer']=222;
    $arr[18]['preview']=208;
    ksort($arr);
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

It will sort according to key in ascending order and if you want descending order so you can use `krsort()` `function (y)`